# How to print out the HttpWebRequest in C#?

Tags: c#, http, https, httpwebrequest, sniffing

I'm having a problem with a POST I'm doing using the HttpWebRequest object from C#. In order to analyze the problem I would like to know exactly what is being sent over the wire. The problem is that I'm also using HTTPS so I can't sniff the wire. I need some way of printing out to the Console all the relevant information of the HttpWebRequest object or something like that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to debug HTTPS traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Could you set a breakpoint in the code and look at the Request object in the debugger and look through the ServerVariables collections to see what it has?  Alternatively, you could do a Response.Write looping over each element in the Request.ServerVariables and see the name/value pairs that are stored in a web page if you want that.